# Migrating topics,ACL and messages from apache kafka to confluent platform

Tags: apache-kafka, data-migration, confluent-platform

We are migrating our application from Apache Kafka to Confluent Platform .

- Apache Kafka version:1.1.0
- Confluent :4.1.0

Tried these options:

1. Manually copying the zookeeper logs and Kafka Logs- Not an optimal way 
   because of volume and data correctness.
2. Mirror Maker - This will replicate newly created topics and ACL. It will not 
   migrate old details in Apache Kafka

Please suggest better approaches on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your existing Kafka and Zookeeper installation.

Confluent does not change any way these run or manage data.

You can configure the REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Control Center, KSQL, etc. to use your existing bootstrap servers or Zookeeper connection; nothing should need migrated, you're only adding extra consumer/producer services which just happen to be provided by Confluent.

If you later plan on upgrading your brokers, then you can start up new ones from the Confluent package, migrate the partitions, then shut down the old ones. Similarly for Zookeeper, but make sure that you have at least 2 up during this process, and always have an odd number of them available after your transition